# Laravel Eloquent Select Issue

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Here is my Query

```
$TagDatas = TagModel::whereIn('TagId', array($BlogData->Tagged))->get();
```

The `$BlogData->Tagged` has the value `1,2,3` (Not as array but just as a character)

Here is my Model

```
<?php
class TagModel extends Eloquent
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'AutoID';
    protected $table = 'tag';
```

Then i do

```
@foreach($TagDatas as $TagData)
{{ $TagData->TagName }}
@endforeach
```

It shows only the first element in the tag Table

Even when i debug it shows me

```
 select * from `tag` where `TagId` in (1,2,3)
```

What is that i am missing ?

Comment: If `$BlogData->Tagged` is a string, then explode it to an array before using it your `whereIn()`, otherwise it will be treated as a literal string... Laravel uses prepared statements, so the bindvar will be a single string: the statement should be `select * from \`tag\` where \`TagId\` in (?)`, and a single bindvar of `1,2,3`

Comment: Should i do **$myArray = explode(',', $BlogData->Tagged);** ?

Comment: `$TagDatas = TagModel::whereIn('TagId', explode(',', $BlogData->Tagged))->get();`

Comment: It was done ! Thanks. Can you post it as an answer with Little explanation ! Coz it helped me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass a string value to the `wherein()`, it will be treated as a literal string when Eloquent prepares its bindings, so the statement that is actually executed will be

```
select * from `tag` where `TagId` in ('1,2,3')
```

You need to pass each value 1, 2 and 3 as a separate array entries so that they will be bound correctly

```
$TagDatas = TagModel::whereIn('TagId', explode(',', $BlogData->Tagged))
    ->get();
```

so that wherein will treat the three as individual array elements, giving an executed query of

```
select * from `tag` where `TagId` in (1, 2, 3)
```